# Wicket: Loosing form input on page re-render

Tags: wicket, wicket-6

I have pages with forms. Everything is working fine. Except, that there is a link (language selecter) on the pages. The requirement is, that when the user has already input in the form fields and than (without submitting the form) is clicking the link, all input should be retained.

If the link would be part of the form, this could easily archived via a SubmitLink and `submitLink.setDefaultFormProcessing(false);`

Unfortunately, this link has no knowledge of the form(s) on this page.

Any pointers if this is solvable? Of course, validation should not be triggered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. client-side JavaScript solution
2. wrap complete page content in a form
   (yes, Wicket allows nesting of forms) and use an SubmitLink with
   defaultFormProcessing=false
3. add an AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior
   to all your form fields, so the input is always sent to the server

Comment: Personally I would use solution 2

Comment: Thanks @svenmeier. Option 2 would be my (technically) preferred option. Unfortunately, blandly putting a form around <wicket:child> disturbs the component hierarchy and we would have to adjust all pages. Not sure if we can manage that 6 weeks before launch. The 3 option would be easy to implement (we already have a form we use everywhere for error highlighting and such. On the other hand, doing a Ajax call  every time a user changes a input field .. , don't know. How would the 1. option work?

Comment: Option 1? I don't know, I haven't done it yet :P ... loop over all inputs, store values somewhere, initiate an Ajax request and restore the values afterwards.

Comment: Due to the amount of work involved with the 2. option,  we will properly go for 3.  
Thanks for your input.